# Batch list folder contents, then echo results as options to be set as variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

I usually like to try to work these out myself, but at the moment I have to admit I don't know where to start with this one. Hoping someone could kindly steer me in the right direction at least.

I have a folder with a number of .txt files

```
Text1.txt
Text2.txt
Text3.txt
```

In my windows bat file I need to list the contents of said folder and set them as options to be set as variables.
example:

```
cls
echo[
echo[                  Please select an option
echo[        
echo                          (1) Text1
echo                          (2) Text2
echo                          (3) Text3
echo[
set /p option=Type your selection (1-3) and press ENTER=

if !option!==1 set var=Text1
if !option!==2 set var=Text2
if !option!==3 set var=Text3
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated, this forum has been great.

*Edit
here is something I tried

```
cls
echo[
echo[                  Please select an option
echo[        
dir /b "*.txt"
echo[
set /p option=Type your selection (1-3) and press ENTER=

if !option!==1 set var=text1
if !option!==2 set var=text2
if !option!==3 set var=text3
```

it works, but does not add the numbers (1) before the options, and it also has them aligned left not centred.

```
                  Please select an option

text1.txt
text2.txt
text3.txt

Type your selection (1-3) and press ENTER=
```

Comment: How many files do you have to list as a choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different solutions you can build, here are 2 examples.

If you have only a few files you can utilize `choice`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=1,*delims=[]" %%i in ('dir /b /a:-d *.txt ^| find /v /n ""') do (
    echo %%i. %%j
    set "cnt=!cnt!%%i"
    set "fchoice%%i=%%~j"
)
choice /c %cnt% /m "Choose"
echo you chose !fchoice%errorlevel%!
```

if you have many files though, `choice` might not be a viable option, then revert to `set /p`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=1,*delims=[]" %%i in ('dir /b /a:-d *.txt ^| find /v /n ""') do (
    echo %%i. %%j
    set "cnt=!cnt!%%i"
    set "fchoice%%i=%%~j"
    set "fin=%%i"
)
set /p "chosen=Select a file by number: "
for /l %%i in (1,1,%fin%) do if "%chosen%" == "%%i" set "check=1"
if not defined check echo Incorrect choice selected & goto :EOF
echo you chose !fchoice%chosen%!
```

Comment: That's perfect Gerhard, thanks a million mate.
The number of txt files will vary, and can exceed 50+

Thanks again, and to the others who tried to help :)

Comment: @rojo, yes, but OP never mentioned tha the files contains exclamation marks. As per the second comment, well, the first solution uses `choice` but it will be limited to the use of upper, lower case and combination of numbers and special characters to make it work on larger number of files. Such choices becomes messy, but it is very easy to eliminate incorrect choices for `set /p`. Let me add that for you. :)

Comment: add the check for incorrect input to the second comment you made, @rojo

Comment: @Gerhard, no clue why my comment got deleted.  I didn't do it.  Anyway, the reason I mentioned exclamation marks within the txtfile file names is I'm trying to teach a batch scripting rookie the down side of always leaving delayed expansion enabled. Nothing against the quality of your solution nor your interpretation of OP's requirements, but solving this specific problem gives a man a fish. I prefer to teach a man to fish.

Comment: @Gerhard I've got a fun challenge for you. OP said he would have 50+ files. How would you columnify the output so the user can avoid scrolling? I'll work on it as well when I get time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this were any other language what would you do?  Probably populate an array with your directory listing, right?  Then use that array to pair menu option with file choice?  Well, don't let the fact that the Batch language doesn't have arrays stop you.  They're easy enough to simulate.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

rem // init array index
set file.length=0

rem // for each .txt file in the current directory
for %%I in (*.txt) do (

    rem // It's good practice only to enable delayed expansion when needed, as
    rem // otherwise it can mangle values containing exclamation marks
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    
    rem // use a "for /f" command to endlocal while reading the value of
    rem // !file.length!.  This preserves exclamation marks in file names.
    for /f %%# in ("!file.length!") do endlocal & set "file[%%~#]=%%~I"
    
    rem // set /a doesn't require delayed expansion.  It just works.
    set /a file.ubound = file.length, file.length += 1 
)

rem // Display the collection of variables named file...something.
set file
```

There you go.  The last line should show you a list of all the variables beginning with `file`, including the simulated `.length` and `.ubound` properties.  From there, just use a `for /L %%I in (0, 1, %file.ubound%)` to display your menu.

---

Here's a bit more.  Firstly, I read [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71947083/batch-list-folder-contents-then-echo-results-as-options-to-be-set-as-variables/71947866#comment127143151_71952430) explaining that the number of txt files could exceed 50.  By default, the Windows cmd console is 24 lines.  Wouldn't it be nice to columnify the output so the user doesn't have to scroll?  I wrote a utility script that will take a flat list and columnify it based on the number of rows in the current cmd console.  Save this as...

**columnify.bat:**

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

if "%~1"=="test" (
    rem // this errors if there's redirected input buffer waiting
    timeout /t 0 /nobreak >NUL 2>NUL && (
        echo Usage: command list output ^| %~nx0
        echo or %~nx0 ^< txtfile containing a list
        echo;
        echo Hit Ctrl-C to exit.
    )
    exit
)

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=," %%I in (
    `powershell "(Get-Host).UI.RawUI.WindowSize.toString()"`
) do (
    rem // detect whether input buffer has content waiting
    start /b cmd /c "%~f0" test
    cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" %%I %%J
)

goto :EOF

@end // end Batch / begin JScript hybrid code

var stdin = WSH.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(0).ReadAll();
    cols = WSH.Arguments(0) * 1 - 1,
    rows = WSH.Arguments(1) * 1 - 4;

var out = stdin.split(/\r?\n/), buffer = [], maxlen, col = 0;
if (rows > out.length) { rows = out.length; }

while (out.length) {
    buffer[col] = [];
    maxlen = 0;
    while (buffer[col].length < rows) {
        val = out.length ? out.shift() : '';
        buffer[col].push(val);
        if (maxlen < val.length) maxlen = val.length;
    }
    for (var i = buffer[col].length; i--;) {
        while (buffer[col][i].length < maxlen) { buffer[col][i] += ' '; }
    }
    col++;
}

for (var i=0; i < buffer[0].length; i++) {
    var line = [];
    for (var j=0; j < col; j++) {
        line.push(buffer[j][i]);
    }
    WSH.Echo(line.join(' ').substr(0, cols));
}
```

Now your main script can make use of `columnify.bat` by piping output through it.

```js
@echo off & setlocal
rem // All the same stuff as above, but without the comments.

set file.length=0
for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f %%# in ("!file.length!") do endlocal & set "file[%%~#]=%%~I"
    set /a file.ubound = file.length, file.length += 1 
)

cls

:displaymenu
echo Always press your luck.  Which file do you choose?
echo;
( for /L %%I in (0,1,%file.ubound%) do @(
        call echo %%I: %%file[%%~I]%%
) ) | columnify
echo;

set /P "choice=Enter a number: "
if %choice% GEQ 0 if %choice% LEQ %file.ubound% (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo You chose !file[%choice%]!.  Neat.
    endlocal
) else (
    cls
    powershell "write-host -f red 'Invalid response.  Enter a number between 0 and %file.ubound%.'"
    goto displaymenu
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply rojo, I posted my solution at the same time :)
I appreciate you taking the time thanks.

Comment: @UNAVOWED Your solution relies on statically setting var1=file1, var2=file2, etc.  Didn't you want the script to build its list of files dynamically?

Comment: yes you are correct. I will take a look at your solution now :)

Comment: sorry rojo, I am struggling to put this together still.
What now happens here?
set /p option=Type your selection and press ENTER=
set var=

I'm not sure how to set the selected option as the variable sorry.

Comment: `set "var=file[%option%]"`

Comment: @UNAVOWED I added a more complete example.  See whether that helps you.